# undefined method `handle_asynchronously' for AsyncTask:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller, delayed-job

I get this error when I try to run delayed job in my controller. Have anyone else come across it before?

I have followed all the steps on the git file for the gem and it installed correctly. 
I created another class after my create class in my controller that will be handling the delay and then call that class from the create class. 
Do I need to have the delay class in a separate file to the controller?

Answer (score 2):

Just restart your server.
Shut down the server and start it again.